# Simulating probability with stdlib.h on device (e.g. iPhone)

Tags: ios, random, simulation, probability

Stupid stupid question but here we are..

so, I want to generate some random events in an iOS application (in my case a game). I have written a function "verifyEvents" that I call each time I load a particular view (game scene).

To associate a probability to an event I assigned a value to each event (e.g. kill player: 0.05, give extra bonus 0.08).

In the function I generate a random number using CCRANDOM_0_1(), an iOS macro based on the random() function defined in stdlib.h. If the number is less than the assigned value I trigger the event (below there is the code).

```
#define CCRANDOM_0_1() ((random() / (float)0x7fffffff ))
```

**Is this the best approach or do you use something else in your apps?**

```
-(void) verifyEvents
{
    float value = CCRANDOM_0_1() ;
    float eventPValue = 0.05f;

    if(value<eventPValue){
        CCLOG(@"EVENT!");
    }
}
```

Comment: although this is a programming question, you'll get much better answers for this @ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @lukya cool thanks! I will create an account and post a question also there :)

Comment: that's the link to the question as posted on gamedev.. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33236/simulating-probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, following the suggestion of @lukya I asked the question on gamedev and did some more research. By far I got two answer which seem quiet interesting (which should be read together with the comments on my question).

EDIT: Forgot to put the link here as well (was only in the comment):
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33236/simulating-probability